# <br/> does not work for dynamically set "value"-Attribute of h:outputtext

Tags: jsf

I have the following problem:
The "value"-Attribute of my "h:outbuttext" is set dynamically as follows:

```
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.getText()}" style="position: relative;" escape="false"/>
```

So the "value"-Attribute of "h:outbuttext" looks like this:

```
    1. Cars<br/>2. Busses<br/>3. Plains
```

And my expected result is:

1. Cars
2. Busses
3. Plains

But the <'br/'>s are not recognized as  word wrap and my actual result looks like this:

```
1. Cars<br/>2. Busses<br/>3. Plains
```

When I set the "value"-Attribute of my "h:outputtext" as a raw string like this:

```
    <h:outputText value="1. Cars&lt;br/&gt;2. Busses&lt;br/&gt;3. Plains" style="position: relative;" escape="false"/>
```

then I get the expected result.

So my question is, how do I get the <'br'/> work for dynamically set "value"-Attributes?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Problem suggests that the string returned by `getText()` is already escaped by itself. I.e. it already contains `&lt;` instead of `<` and so on. To confirm that, log/print it to stdout instead of printing it via HTML (in a JSF page). In that case you would need to take a step back and solve over there where it actually got escaped.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you very much!!!The problem was, that I used "&lt;br/&gt" bean side and I think your suggestion, that the string was already escaped is true. I rplaced "&lt;br/&gt" with "<br/>" and now it just works fine!!! Thank you very much again!!!